# Why are `take` and `drop` defined for negative arguments?

Tags: haskell

The [Prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) shows examples for `take` and `drop` with negative arguments:

```
take (-1) [1,2] == []
drop (-1) [1,2] == [1,2]
```

Why are these defined the way they are, when e.g. `x !! (-1)` does the "safer" thing and crashes? It seems like a hackish and very un-Haskell-like way to make these functions total, even when the argument doesn't make sense. Is there some greater design philosophy behind this that I'm not seeing? Is this behavior guaranteed by the standard, or is this just how GHC decided to implement it?

Comment: There are reasonable and often useful things to do when the arguments goes out of bounds: "return the entire original list" or "return the empty list". You cannot sensibly define `(!! (-1))` at all, there's no fallback value to give back.

Comment: Fun fact: the semantics changed between the Haskell 98 and 2010 reports. The [example implementation](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/list.html) in 98 used `error` if the list wasn't empty and `n` was negative, whereas the 2010 variant shows that negative values have the same effect as `take 0`.

Comment: @Zeta: that's fascinating, great find!

Comment: I believe the reason is the same as why (e.g.) python slicing works even for indices that are out of range: in **most** circumstances that is the result you actually want. Most of the times when you use slicing being a bit "sloppy" (i.e. avoiding thinking about special cases and things like that) simplifies the code and you later find out that this kind of thing make things work even in the special cases. Without these you'd have to always check for the lengths etc. and 99% of the times you'd always do the same thing (like returning `[]` or the whole list).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There would be mainly one good reason to make `take` partial: it could guarantee that the result list, if there is one, has always the requested number of elements.

Now, `take` already violates this in the other direction: when you try to take more elements than there are in the list, is simply takes *as many as there are*, i.e. fewer than requested. Perhaps not the most elegant thing to do, but in practice this tends to work out quite usefully.

The main invariant for `take` is combined with `drop`:

```
take n xs ++ drop n xs  ≡  xs
```

and that holds true even if `n` is negative.

A good reason not to check the length of the list is that it makes the functions perform nicely on lazy infinite lists: for instance,

```
take hugeNum [1..] ++ 0 : drop hugeNum [1..]
```

will immediately give `1` as the first result element. This would not be possible if `take` and `drop` first had to check whether there are enough elements in the input.

Comment: Accepting this answer, because `take` already violating this in the other direction in a *useful* way is a pretty good argument: I can't quite see why you'd want to rely on how `take (-1)` behaves, but I bet making it consistent the way you describe was part of the idea.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's a matter of design choice here.

The current definition ensures that the property

```
take x list ++ drop x list == list
```

holds for any `x`, including negative ones as well as those larger than `length list`.

I can however see the value in a variant of `take`/`drop` which errors out: sometimes a crash is preferred to a wrong result.

Comment: Of course, a partial implementation would still keep the `(++) . (take&&&drop) ≡ id` property.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Wouldn't the LHS just crash? (BTW, your equation does not type check)

Comment: that was pseudocode. What I meant was, if `drop n xs` and `take n xs` both yielded `Nothing` when `n ∉ [0 .. length xs-1]`, then we would always have `liftA2 (++) (take n xs) (drop n xs) ≡ Just xs`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Ah, I see. I assumed "partial implementation" to return bottom, not `Nothing`.

Answer (score 4):

> `x !! (-1)` does the "safer" thing and crashes

**Crashing is not safe**.  Making a function non-total destroys your ability
to reason about the behaviour of a function based on its type.

Let us imagine that `take` and `drop` did have "crash on negative" behaviour. Consider their type:

```
take, drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

One thing this type definitely *doesn't* tell you that this function could crash!  It's helpful to reason about code as though we were using a total language, even though we are not - an idea called *[fast and loose reasoning](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-et-al-popl2006.pdf)* - but to be able to do that, you have to avoid using (and writing) non-total functions as much as possible.

What to do, then, about operations that might fail or have no result?  Types are the answer!  A *truly safe* variant of `(!!)` would have a type that models the failure case, like:

```
safeIndex :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
```

This is preferable to the type of `(!!)`,

```
(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a
```

Which, by simple observation, can have no (total) inhabitants - you cannot "invent" an `a` if the list is empty!

Finally, let us return to `take` and `drop`.  Although their type doesn't fully say what the behaviour is, coupled with their names (and ideally a few QuickCheck properties) we get a pretty good idea.  As other responders have pointed out, this behaviour is appropriate in many cases.  If you *truly* have a need to reject negative length inputs, you don't have to choose between non-totality (crashing) or the possibility of surprising behaviour (negative length accepted) - model the possible outcomes responsibly with types.

This type makes it clear that there is "no result"
for some inputs:

```
takePos, dropPos :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe [a]
```

Better still, this type uses natural numbers;
functions with this type cannot even be
applied to a negative number!

```
takeNat, dropNat :: Nat -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: I understand your reasoning, and I really try to avoid total functions for the reasons you mentioned, but I still stand by the fact that I'd rather have things go *obviously completely wrong* when I do something weird like `take (-1) [5]` than have them silently return a value that's "close enough" to what I *might* want. I see how it's better in some cases, but there are other instances where `length (take n xs) == n` being a valid law would be really nice!

Comment: Compare this to the situation with `tail`: you could perfectly define `tail [] = []` (i.e. `tail = drop 1`) and it would do maybe what you want... sometimes. But there's a [very good reason why it doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). (Of course, dependent types are the "nicest" solution to decisions like this, but that's a whole nother story...)

Comment: I am more astonished when a function does something that the type says it shouldn't do, such as crashing :)  You don't have to choose between totality and least-astonishment - you just need functions with useful types, e.g. `betterTail :: [a] -> Maybe [a]`.